# How to use Dialogflow environments (beta feature) in nodejs-dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

How to call detectIntent but with specified Environment (beta feature) using Dialogflow nodejs SDK ([nodejs-dialogflow](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow))?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `dialogflow.v2beta1.SessionsClient` & `.environmentSessionPath` instead of `.sessionPath` to generate the session that is sent on `detectIntent`

```
const client = new dialogflow.v2beta1.SessionsClient({});

const sessionPath = client.environmentSessionPath(project, environment, user, session);

// The text query request.
const request = {
  session: sessionPath,
  queryInput: {
    text: {
      text: 'hello'
    }
  }
};
```

This is the template for session environment path:

```
projects/{project}/agent/environments/{environment}/users/{user}/sessions/{session}
```

You can read the library code regarding this answer at https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/src/v2beta1/sessions_client.js#L353

More info at: https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents/versions-environments

Comment: Thank you, grate answer! One more question. What is "user" parameter? I used string "-" like in example https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents/versions-environments and it worked.

Comment: Being honest, it's not documented anywhere, I guess is for future use, where there could be environments by users. So right now the only possible value is `-`

Comment: how to test that method ? shoudl i do POST to API of detectIntent ??

Comment: So that "-" for user is a fallback in case the API consumer doesn't specify a user themselves. It's an optional thing you can set for yourself: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/src/v2beta1/sessions_client.ts#L348

Comment: Do you know if I can define a sessionPath with both environment and location (europe-west1) for now I see two distinct methods `.environmentSessionPath` and `.projectLocationAgentSessionPath` but no one for making both params effective.